# Find next element by class (same level in hierarchy)

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="desc"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="desc"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="desc"></div>
</div>
```

For every n number of items there will be a div with a class of `.desc`, where the content of a data attribute from a previous `.item` is inserted.

Essentially, if you click an item it should always push the data attribute content to the next `.desc` (not necessarily the nearest).

The closest I've got to achieving what I want is:

```
$(this).next().siblings('.desc').show().html(data);
```

(where `$this` is the .item from the click function).

However, this pushes the content in to every `.item` div, and not just the next.

Comment: please include your click function and if it's important the element with class `person-desc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `nextAll(selector).first()`:

```
$(this).nextAll(".desc").first().show().html(data);
```

(I've used `.desc` rather than `.person-desc` as the former matches your markup.)

Docs:

- [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)
- [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Live Example:

```js
$(".container").on("click", ".item", function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".desc").first().html($(this).html());
});
```

```css
.desc {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
Click an item, and its text will be shown in the next .desc element after it (the ones with yellow backgrounds).
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="desc"></div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="desc"></div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="desc"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly - not sure how I missed nextAll in the docs. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.NextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) for this. Then you just have to select the first item with `first()`. This will give you the next element with the specified selector.

```
$(this).nextAll(".desc").first();
```